# python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

whats the difference between '{m}' and '{m,n}?' in http://docs.python.org/library/re.html it says '{m,n}?' matches numbers in range m to n times, but it is not a greedy search. Therefore if its not a greedy search wouldn't it only match up to m no matter what?

Comment: I'm not sure about Python-flavored regexes, but most regex flavors (and most programming languages for that matter) have a few functionally identical constructs. This isn't one, but you shouldn't be surprised if you find them.

Comment: @chris: when in doubt, it's easy to compare the regex system from several languages using online tools: PHP and javascript got http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ while python got http://ksamuel.pythonanywhere.com. here you can see easily it's not a new construct.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`{m,n}?` will preferably match only `m` repetitions, but it will expand as needed up to `n` repetitions if that's necessary for a longer match.

Compare `^x{2}y$` and `^x{2,4}?y$`:

The former will fail on `xxxy` whereas the latter will match.

**To summarize:**

`x{m}`: Match `x` *exactly* `m` times.

`x{m,n}`: Try to match `x` `n` times, but if that causes the overall match to fail, give back as needed, but match at least `m` times (greedy quantifier).

`x{m,n}?`: Try to match `x` `m` times, but if that causes the overall match to fail, expand as needed, but match at most `n` times (lazy quantifier).

Comment: @Marco: No, you should never mark a solution as an answer just 15 minutes in.  Always wait an hour or so.  (In my opinion, this is a rather roundabout, not very clear explanation.)

Comment: side note - why does python not use self describing names for classes ? `re` should be `RegularExpression` instead of `re`. Is there any reason for not doing it that way ?

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to see with an example using two matching groups:

```
>>> re.match(r'(x{1,3}?)(.*)', 'xxxxx').groups()
('x', 'xxxx')
>>> re.match(r'(x{1,3})(.*)', 'xxxxx').groups()
('xxx', 'xx')
```

In other words, {n,m} and {n,m}? are both able to match exactly the same things; what it changes is where the groupings happen when there's more than one way to match.